# Xcode 6.0.1 segmentation fault at compile time with Swift project

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

I've a segmentation fault when I try to compile my Swift project.

Here is a simplified version of my code which causes the error:

```
enum PluginType
{
    case PluginC
    case PluginD
}

class Plugin
{
    var pluginType : PluginType
    var setter : Void -> Void
    var unsetter : Void -> Void

    init(pluginType : PluginType, setter : Void -> Void, unsetter : Void -> Void)
    {
        self.pluginType = pluginType
        self.setter = setter
        self.unsetter = unsetter
    }
}

@objc protocol BProtocol
{
    func getPlugins() -> [Plugin]
}

class B : BProtocol
{
    var a : AProtocol?

    func getPlugins() -> [Plugin]
    {
        return [Plugin(pluginType : .PluginC, setter : a!.setPluginC, unsetter : a!.unsetPluginC),
            Plugin(pluginType : .PluginD, setter : a!.setPluginD, unsetter: a!.unsetPluginD)]
    }
}

@objc protocol AProtocol
{
    func setPluginC()
    func unsetPluginC()
    func setPluginD()
    func unsetPluginD()
}

class A : AProtocol
{
    var b : BProtocol?

    func setPluginC()
    {

    }

    func unsetPluginC()
    {

    }

    func setPluginD()
    {

    }

    func unsetPluginD()
    {

    }
}
```

The problems come from this method:

```
    func getPlugins() -> [Plugin]
    {
        return [Plugin(pluginType : .PluginC, setter : a!.setPluginC, unsetter : a!.unsetPluginC),
            Plugin(pluginType : .PluginD, setter : a!.setPluginD, unsetter: a!.unsetPluginD)]
    }
```

The problem is caused by the setter and unsetter that I initialize.

Here's the error on Xcode:

> 0  swift                    0x000000010456a028
>   llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(__sFILE*) + 40 1  swift
>   0x000000010456a514 SignalHandler(int) + 452 2 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff9596f5aa _sigtramp + 26 3 
>   libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000007f83527198b _sigtramp + 2677023739 4 
>   swift                    0x00000001049290df
>   swift::AbstractStorageDecl::hasObjCGetterAndSetter() const + 31 5 
>   swift                    0x0000000104929205
>   swift::AbstractStorageDecl::requiresObjCGetterAndSetter() const + 69 6
>   swift                    0x00000001039ff3f4
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitGetAccessor(swift::SILLocation,
>   swift::AbstractStorageDecl*, llvm::ArrayRef,
>   swift::Lowering::RValueSource&&, bool, swift::Lowering::RValue&&,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 68 7  swift
>   0x0000000103a15ca4
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitRValueForPropertyLoad(swift::SILLocation,
>   swift::Lowering::ManagedValue, bool, swift::VarDecl*,
>   llvm::ArrayRef, bool, swift::Type,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 1284 8  swift
>   0x0000000103a2a012 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous
>   namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void,
>   void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 28402 9  swift
>   0x0000000103a2b6ed
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitRValueAsSingleValue(swift::Expr*,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 45 10 swift
>   0x00000001039f3720
>   swift::Lowering::RValueSource::getAsSingleValue(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) && + 176 11 swift
>   0x0000000103a44154
>   swift::Lowering::RValueSource::forwardInto(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&,
>   swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::Lowering::Initialization*,
>   swift::Lowering::TypeLowering const&) && + 260 12 swift
>   0x0000000103a4400e
>   swift::Lowering::RValueSource::materialize(swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction&,
>   swift::Lowering::AbstractionPattern, swift::SILType) && + 334 13 swift
>   0x0000000103a340fc
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitInjectOptionalValueInto(swift::SILLocation,
>   swift::Lowering::RValueSource&&, swift::SILValue,
>   swift::Lowering::TypeLowering const&) + 268 14 swift
>   0x0000000103a2b1fb swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous
>   namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void,
>   void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 32987 15 swift
>   0x0000000103a2a325 swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous
>   namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void,
>   void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*,
>   swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 29189 16 swift
>   0x0000000103a2b63f
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitIgnoredExpr(swift::Expr*) + 191
>   17 swift                    0x0000000103a483f9
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::visitBraceStmt(swift::BraceStmt*) +
>   297 18 swift                    0x0000000103a4b2d4
>   swift::ASTVisitor::visit(swift::Stmt*) + 148 19 swift
>   0x0000000103a188c3
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 243
>   20 swift                    0x00000001039f8646
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitFunction(swift::FuncDecl*) + 230 21
>   swift                    0x0000000103a12763
>   swift::ASTVisitor::visit(swift::Decl*) + 355 22 swift
>   0x0000000103a1112b SILGenType::emitType() + 203 23 swift
>   0x0000000103a0c0fe
>   swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::visitNominalTypeDecl(swift::NominalTypeDecl*)
>   + 30 24 swift                    0x00000001039fa5cb swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*,
>   unsigned int) + 411 25 swift                    0x00000001039fa88f
>   swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::Module*, swift::SourceFile*,
>   swift::Optional) + 335 26 swift
>   0x00000001039fa9d8 swift::performSILGeneration(swift::SourceFile&,
>   swift::Optional) + 72 27 swift
>   0x00000001038dfda9 frontend_main(llvm::ArrayRef, char
>   const*, void*) + 3353 28 swift                    0x00000001038dd94d
>   main + 1677 29 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff99b5c5fd start + 1
>   30 libdyld.dylib            0x000000000000015a start + 1716140894

I'm looking for a workaround to avoid the "Segmentation Fault" with the compiler.

Any suggestions?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found a workaround:

```
func getPlugins() -> [Plugin]
{
    return [Plugin(pluginType : .PluginC, setter : { a!.setPluginC() }, unsetter : { a!.unsetPluginC() }),
        Plugin(pluginType : .PluginD, setter : { a!.setPluginD() }, unsetter: { a!.unsetPluginD() })]
}
```

This successfully works with Xcode 6.1